# How to keep 2 buttons at bottom of card with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I was wondering how to fix the following buttons in bootstrap. I want both buttons to be at the bottom of the card as well as have a little bit of gap between them maybe 5 pixels??

---

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="url/avatars-Y8yyODrfuoRdxOFy-0OpzDQ-t240x240-2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body  d-flex flex-column">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Barber Tools</h5>
                    <a class="mt-auto" href="url/"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100" value="View Shop"></a>
                    <a class="mt-auto" href="url/?listing_type=gd_place&amp;pid=785"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning w-100" value="Edit Shop"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        ...duplicated columns
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/card/#card-groups; pay special attention to the example titled "When using card groups with footers, their content will automatically line up".

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instructions: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/card/#card-groups

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">  
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="card">
                <img style="width: auto;  height: 200px; object-fit: cover;" src="link-t240x240-2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Barber Tools</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary w-100" href="<?php echo $view_BS_loction_URL?>" role="button" style="margin-top:6px;"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> View Shop</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning w-100" href="<?php echo $edit_BS_location_URL?>" role="button" style="margin-top:6px;"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> Edit Shop</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger w-100" href="<?php echo $view_BS_loction_URL?>" role="button" style="margin-top:6px;"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete Shop</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

RESULT:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try below something structure with bootstrap css class. You can use [Block Button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/#block-buttons) for set button 100% and gap. You should not use inline css. also, You can use [spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/) class for margin and padding.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-4">  
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="card">
                <img style="width: auto;  height: 200px; object-fit: cover;" src="link-t240x240-2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Barber Tools</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer d-grid gap-2">
                    <a href="<?php echo $view_BS_loction_URL?>" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> View Shop</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $edit_BS_location_URL?>" role="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> Edit Shop</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $view_BS_loction_URL?>" role="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete Shop</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```